# Put three items from different tables on a single line

Tags: lua, lua-table

So I'm trying to create a list of console commands for a game, and to make it slightly nicer I want to have three commands on a single line.

Example:

```
Commands.afk.Args.Name = "!afk";
Commands.transfer.Args.Name = "!transfer";
Commands.jump.Args.Name = "!jump";
```

Would be:

[ !afk ]   [ !jump ]   [ !transfer ]

I *think* I know how to do this (by using `table.concat`), but this code also requires to verify that the commands we're forwarding belong to the user's access group (we don't want to send them administrator commands if they're just a guest for instance).

`Commands.[commandname].Args.Access` returns a number between 1 and 6, which corresponds to the membership grade that the user belongs to. The function `Core:GetAccess(player)` (where `player` is the user's unique entity table) returns the membership group that the user belongs to- the `Commands.[commandname].Args.Access` and `Core:GetAccess(player)` need to match in order to allow the command to be listed.

I'm not too fussed about formatting at the moment, I'm just more concerned whether my specific usage case is actually possible or not.
If it is possible, can a simple `table.concat` be used?

I've looked on the internet for the solution to this, but nothing appears to match my specifric usage case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just iterate through all commands and set it inside loop.

```
for i,v in pairs(Commands) do
    v.Args=v.Args or {};
    v.Args["name"]=i;
end
```

Just call this little loop right after you load all chat-commands.

Answer (score 2):

`table.concat` only formats plain string items from array-like tables.

If you need to do more complicated work then that that you need to write some code yourself.

Something like the following might work:

```
local available_commands = {}
for cmd, tab in pairs(Commands) do
    if cmd.Args.Access == Core:GetAccess(player) then
        available_commands[#available_commands + 1] = "[!"..cmd.Args.Name.."]"
    end
end
local display_string = table.concat(available_commands)
print(display_string)
```

Comment: Instead of performing two concatenations per entry, you could assign them plainly to the array and do this: `local display_string = '[!' .. table.concat(available_commands, '] [!') .. ']'` This of course assumes at least one command, but it's a neat shortcut.